# CSS changes have no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nivo-slider

I have installed "Easy Nivo Slider" plugin for WordPress in order to show a slideshow in the heading of the site I'm working on and it seems that the plugin generates things like thumbnail navigation and etc inside the IMG tag with javascript. I have never seen this method before and all the changes (margins, paddings) have no effect even close to what I'd like to get. Basically, what I want is to have a slider with a title and description place and thumbnail navigation (whereas the thumbnail is not the smaller image of it, but another one, custom one, defined in a post's custom fields (I think I can do that myself). All I need is to be able to use CSS however I want it to, because right now the only function that actually responded was the font-size.

You can see the half-done site live at http://work.codera.in/re to get a look at the code and to get a glimpse of how I want to be able to modify it in the end result is here: https://minus.com/lbyerG4OncvwdZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-nivo-slider/ or http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-nivo-slider/ . From what i can see here wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-nivo-slider/  easy nivo plugin appears to be broken.

Comment: I will give it a shot I'll report back as soon as possible.

Comment: Well, it works - sort of - thanks for pointing the real nivo slider out either way.